# Bounding boxes around all the different objects in an image

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection

Given an image, I want to get bounding boxes around all the objects detected in the image. The type of objects is not of concern to me. Is there an effective way to do so or at least tell me where should I start?

I searched about it and found that given an image we can detect the object of a defined type once the network learns to detect that object. But the image in my case can have any random objects and it is not feasible to train a network to detect all the different objects there are. Can we use the fact that we don't want to know the type of the object, just something that distinguishes one object from another and bounds it in a box?

Please help me out in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a model like [YOLO](https://www.kaggle.com/valentynsichkar/yolo-coco-data) trained on [COCO dataset](http://cocodataset.org/#download) that has 80 classes of objects. But to detect any object of any type, I have not seen any model like that.